# How to create a multilevel dropdown menu in Angular 12 using bootstrap 5?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5

I want to create a multilevel dropdown in angular 12 using Bootstrap 5. I would like to know how one would go about creating it?.

[Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps7J3.png)

Thanks!

Comment: SO isn't a platform to ask for ready-made code. You'll have to do some research yourself, try things out and only if you're still stuck by then, you come here with some code and a proper description of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example of what you trying to achieve

html

```
<div class="container">        
        <ul class="">

            <li class="">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Item 1</a>
                <ul class="">
                    <li class=""><a tabindex="-1"                                        href="#">Item 1 A</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">Item 1 B</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">Item 1 C</a></li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a href="#">Item 1 D </a>
                        <ul class="parent">
                            <li >
                                <a href="#">
                                    Item 1 D1
                                </a>

                            <li ><a href="#"> Item 1 D2</a></li>
                            <li ><a href="#"> Item 1 D3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">Implementation</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">Review</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">Execution Only</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li ><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li ><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
            <li ><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    
</div>
```

css

```
html, body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
 }
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.container {
  height:100%;
}
a {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #fff;
    padding:0px 0px 20px 0px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    height:100%;
}
li {
    padding:20px 20px 0 20px;
    width:100%;
    color:#fff;
}
.container ul {height:100%;}
.container > ul {
    width:250px;
    background-color:#224490;
    position:relative;
    overflow:visible;
}
.container > ul > li {}
.container > ul > li:hover {background-color:#0f1e41;}
.container > ul > li > ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    right:-250px;
    top:0;
    width:250px;
    background-color:#18316a;
}
.container > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
.container > ul > li > ul >li:hover {background-color:#0f1e41;}
.container > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    right:-250px;
    top:0;
    width:250px;
    background-color:#112551;
}
    .container > ul > li > ul > li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
.container > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li:hover {background-color:#0f1e41;}
.container > ul > li > ul > li ul li ul li {
    border-bottom:1px dotted #fff;
    padding:20px;
}
```

You can check the working demo [here](https://codepen.io/vijaykumawat/pen/QWgGxxL) in codepane